# Pin the 5th item of the column or lazyColumn on top of the screen while scrolling the column using android jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-appcompat, android-compose-card

I am new in android jetpack compose i created a list view using lazyColumn that is working fine
but my use case is to pin the 5th or Xth element to the top of the screen while other elements will scroll.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stickyheader` for this.

```
LazyColumn() {
     stickyheader {
         //your xth element
     }
     //your rest of the items
}
```

It will always stick to the top of the lazy column meanwhile rest of the items will be able to scroll underneath it.